# Modify SELECT queries using HTML buttons and output results below

Tags: php, python, html, sql, sqlite

I am creating a timetable system for students and I need to create a GUI for my SQL outputs.

So far I have the HTML form to choose the year of the studies, faculty and the language group. You also need to give a valid password to move to the results of thhe query.

All values from form are then submitted using "SUBMIT" bytton and POST method.

The SQL query itself will be more complex, however I want you to get the concept.

I wish to create (using HTML, SQLite and Python or PHP) the following interface:

http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/1951/qb6n.png

The field with date will be filled from Python using datetime module.

The main task is to create these buttons. Each of them will modify the SQL query as its name shows.

I can calculate e.g. the day before, the week before, the day after and the week after. I don't know how to combine these buttons so that they will get the date from the field on the top, execute e.g. the SQL for the previous day and show results below. If you want to see the next day then you just click the "NEXT DAY" button and BAM! You get the timetable for the chosen day.

I considered two cases:

- to create the HTML website with two frames: the top frame with controls and the bottom frame with results of the query

OR

- the website without frames - the whole page will be recreated after every click and the control buttons will be always created at the top and then the result will be shown.

I also do not know how to "store" the "present" date between these queries. Is there a sort of a global variable to store it?

QUESTIONS:

**How to create those buttons with SQL queries?**

**How to output the SQL query and show the buttons before?**

**How to store the date between queries?**

General comments are welcome in case you cannot give an exact answer.

Ask for details if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using PHP & Ajax/Javascript. I would make a separate PHP file with functions for example

On your HTML page have a script in your head tags to get this data from the PHP page.

```
<script>
function DoRequest(){
$.get('yourfunctions.php', {'action': 'today'}, function(response){
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = response;
});
$.get('yourfunctions.php', {'action': 'yesterday'}, function(response){
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = response;
});
}
</script>
```

and in your body tags

```
<button type="button" onclick="DoRequest()">Load results</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

So your php page could look like this.

```
$todaysdate = //code to get date 
$yesterdaysdate = //code to get date
$dbconn = //connection to your database

switch($action) {
       case 'today':
                   echo Today();
                   break;
       case 'yesterday':
                   echo Yesterday();
                   break;
}

function Today() {
      //Query today's timetable with $todaysdate
    }

function Yesterday() {
      //Query today's timetable with $yesterdaysdate
    }
```

This page should explain how to get the dates and put them into variables [PHP dates](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp)

Also you may need to make your variables global to make them work in the functions

Comment: The main concept is that you have the HTML form where you can select year, groups and input the password. Then, using the `SUBMIT` button, you get a new page that looks like the diagram. Inside this page, I need to get those results. I get the idea with scripts in <header> - however, I miss the point with the `LOAD RESULTS` button. Results shouldn't be presented at the page containing the HTML form. I need to get form on one page and the buttons + query results on the other page. The form will be presented only once, at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry your saying HTML form however the image you linked is using just buttons and the results display below the buttons. Which way are you after, form or buttons??

Comment: The HTML form is before the PHP/CGI page with results. Its diagram: http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/4360/513b.png . It allows you to select your year of studies, your faculty, language group and you also need to input the correct password in an appropriate field. Then you get a new page with the control buttons and the output of queries. I suppose that the first query executed right after you press `SEND REQUEST` should be to display the timetable for today. Then you will be able to choose other days (like the previous day or next week). Diagram is translated to English for you.

Comment: What is the language of the first snippet with <script> </script>? I found that it may be jQuery/Ajax. As I am not familiar with any of them, I will opt for the JavaScript and PHP. However, I consider moving to Python CGI (I will translate your samples to Python). I think of creating a function like getTimetable(date_shift) for buttons so that the "Previous day" will be getTimetable(-1) - by using timeDelta in Python, I will be able to accomplish this. I will try to recreate page after every SELECT and first draw the set of buttons and then show the output with HTML table tags in between.